# Can a JPanel be placed in a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcombobox

So.. I want to use a JPanel to display images and needed instance variables of a certain object. is it possible for each JPanel I make for each individual Object to be displayed as is in a JComboBox? That is, a click on the combo box drops down a number of JPanels, each representing an object. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to display anything besides an image (& possibly a little text) in the combo.?  That can be done using a `JLabel` (which is used by the default `ListCellRenderer` in any case).

Comment: default implementetions knows Icon, ImageIcons as value in XxxComboBoxModel and for Renderer too, I think BasicComboBoxRenderer returns JLabels by default, see Oracle tutorial about JLabel, Icon and JComboBox....

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. What you are looking for is called a renderer. It exists for various Swing components. Take a look at [this short introduction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) under the section "Providing a Custom Renderer".